# How to Group PFObject Array by date

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to Group UITableView cells into sections by date. I'm using Parse server. 
The question is how to Group data from parse server by date.

```
var filteredArray = [PFObject]()
self.filteredArray = Dictionary(grouping: self.inboxArray, by: { $0.createdAt })
```

> Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary Date?,[PFObject]>' to
>   type'[PFObject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *cannot assign* error is very clear:

- *of type* is the actual (right) type on the right side.
- *to type* is the expected (wrong) type on the left side.

The result of `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` – as the type implies – is a **dictionary** with `Date` key and `[PFObject]` value.

You have to declare

```
var filteredDictionary = [Date:[PFObject]]()
```

To use the dictionary as section array get the sorted keys

```
let sections = filteredDictionary.keys.sorted()
```

and to get a row write

```
let section = sections[indexPath.section]
let object = filteredDictionary[section]![indexPath.row]
```